# Kubernetes controller update CR status field with values from pod output in GO

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

Using the [Operator-sdk](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk) I deploy a CR that has a Job with a pod. CR has a Status struct something like below

```golang
type CRStatus struct {
    TestStatus string `json:"testStatus"`
    TestCount int `json:"testCount"`
}
```

The Pod does some processing and prints output TestStatus and TestCount values. How can operator-sdk controller update CR's TestStatus and TestCount fields with values from Pod output of the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a controller (you might have already):

```
operator-sdk add controller --api-version=example.com/v1alpha1 --kind=YourCRApp
```

Then in the implementation, you will want to make use of the Kubernetes Informers/SharedInformers by adding an `AddEventHandler` call to see if any value has changed on any Kubernetes resource. You can find a sample controller in [Kubernetes source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller/blob/release-1.18/controller.go). Also, there are many resources available online that can guide you on how to create the controller and make use of Informers, here are some examples:

- https://gianarb.it/blog/kubernetes-shared-informer
- https://www.firehydrant.io/blog/stay-informed-with-kubernetes-informers/
- https://linuxera.org/writing-operators-using-operator-framework/

Comment: Can I use client in Operator-sdk to retrieve the logs?

Comment: Yes. Technically everything that you can do with `kubectl` you can do with an operator.